# How to implement Camunda SendTask in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am new to Camunda and using the following tasks:

Business Rule Task --> (Gateway) --> Send Task -- > User Task

While using the Send Task, I am implementing the ExecustionListener class. But do not know how to proceed further with inclusion of Business Logic & Service.

Can anyone give me any idea how to implement the Send Task job.

Comment: for giving the best solution put your bpmn in question and if you are using spring you can address top your bean in Execution Listener part with expression listener type , but i'm not sure this is the right solution for you !!! explaining the problem exactly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i think you shouldn't use Execution Listener but a delegate (for sure you can use the listener, but than you have to add the listener also to the task definition.

So just use sendTask with implementation "Java Class".

Add the full class name to "java Class" attribute. (de.foo.bar.delegates.yourSendTaskImpl )

Implementation looks like this:

```
package de.foo.bar.delegates;

import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;
public class yourSendTaskImpl implements JavaDelegate {

    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
       //your code goes here, do whatever you think sendTask should do.
    }
}
```